# Draw 2 edge connect to 2 side of the (circle) shape (1 each)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, edge

I want to draw each to connect to side of the circle. The circle is quite small.

[image: iwant]

Here is what I am doing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{sq1} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{cir} = [circle, minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw=black ]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->]
\tikzstyle{sqvec} = [matrix] 

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [sqvec] (v6) at (2.5,4) {
\node[sq1] {}; &\node[sq1] {}; &\node[sq1] {}; &\node[sq1] {}; &\node[sq1] {};;\\
};      

\node [sqvec] (v7) at (2,10) {
\node[cir] {}; \\
\node[cir] {}; \\
\node[cir] {}; \\
};      

\draw (1,4.5) node (v2) {} -- (4,4.5) node (v3) {} -- (0,4.5) node (v1) {} -- (5,4.5) node (v4) {};
\draw  (v1) edge (v7);
\draw  (v2) edge (v7);
\draw  (v3) edge (v7);
\draw  (v4) edge (v7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result I got from above latex code.
[image: result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `matrix of nodes`, then you can make use of the fact that the nodes are automatically named, and draw lines between the appropriate anchors.

I think it's generally recommended to use `\tikzset{stylename/.style={...}}` instead of `\tikzstyle{stylename}=[...]`, hence that change in the code.

If you want the circles centered above the rectangles, I'd suggest adding `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`, and using `\node [sqvec,nodes={cir},above=3cm of v6] (v7) ...` instead of the explicit coordinate you've used in your code. You can also shift the circles sideways in this case, by adding e.g. `xshift=-5mm` to the node options, as in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{
  sq1/.style={rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
  cir/.style={circle, minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw=black},
  arrow/.style={thick,->},
  sqvec/.style={matrix,matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells},
}
\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [sqvec,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,nodes={sq1}] (v6) at (2.5,4) {
&&&&\\
};      

% \node [sqvec,nodes={cir}] (v7) at (2,10) { % explicit positioning
\node [sqvec,nodes={cir},above=3cm of v6,xshift=-5mm] (v7) { % relative positioning
 \\
 \\ 
 \\
};      

\draw (v6-1-1.north west) -- (v7-2-1.west);
\draw (v6-1-1.north east) -- (v7-3-1.west);
\draw (v6-1-5.north east) -- (v7-2-1.east);
\draw (v6-1-5.north west) -- (v7-3-1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) for the effort. It seems to me the circles are shifted to the left but the OP wants them in the center, as I understand. I may be wrong.

Comment: @CroCo The circles are placed as the OP placed them.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative without `matrix`, which reproduce showed desired result:

[image]

or

[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\tikzset{
  sql/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum size=12mm, outer sep=0pt, align=center},
  cir/.style = {circle,   draw,  minimum size= 3mm, outer sep=0pt, align=center},
        }

\begin{document}
% first image
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm]
\node (s1) [sql] {};
\foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,...,5}
\node (s\i) [sql,right=of s\j] {};
%
\node (c1) [cir, above=22mm of s3] {};
\node (c2) [cir, above=of c1] {};
%
\draw   (s1.north west) -- (c2.west)
        (s1.north east) -- (c1.west)
%
        (s4.north east) -- (c1.east)
        (s5.north east) -- (c2.east)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

% second image
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm, draw=blue!25!gray]
\node (s1) [sql] {};
\foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,...,5}
\node (s\i) [sql,right=of s\j] {};
%
\node (c1) [cir, above=22mm of s3] {};
\node (c2) [cir, above=of c1] {};
%
\draw   (s1.north west) -- (tangent cs:node=c2,point={(s1.north west)},solution=2)
        (s1.north east) -- (tangent cs:node=c1,point={(s1.north east)},solution=2)
%
        (s5.north west) -- (tangent cs:node=c1,point={(s5.north west)},solution=1)
        (s5.north east) -- (tangent cs:node=c2,point={(s5.north east)},solution=1)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified solution using `\foreach` loops and `tangent cs` from `calc` library. All dimensions can be changed as required.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt,outer sep=0pt]

\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
 \draw (\x,0) rectangle ++(1,1) (\x,1)coordinate(p\x);

\path (2.5,4.0)coordinate(center1) 
      (2.5,4.7)coordinate(center2)
      (2.5,5.4)coordinate(center3) 
      (5,1)coordinate(p5);

\foreach \n in {1,2,3}
 \node [circle,draw] (c\n) at (center\n) [minimum size=.7cm] {};

\draw (p0) -- (tangent cs:node=c2,point={(p0)},solution=2)
      (p1) -- (tangent cs:node=c1,point={(p1)},solution=2)
      (p4) -- (tangent cs:node=c1,point={(p4)},solution=1)
      (p5) -- (tangent cs:node=c2,point={(p5)},solution=1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]